# Pyspark parse year week to date partially working

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Dataframe having YearWeek format which needs to be converted to Date format. Code snippet as below:

```py
week_df.withColumn("date", to_date(col("BIC_YCALWK_TO"), "yyyyw"))
```

| BIC_YCALWK_TO | date |
| --- | --- |
| 202252 | 2022-12-18 |
| 201553 | null |
| 201901 | null |
| 999952 | 9999-12-19 |
| 201501 | null |
| 999952 | 9999-12-19 |

As it can be seen, not all are getting parsed. Weeks ending with 53 or 01 are not working. Also please note that Monday should be considered as week start day. This is done in Azure Databricks Environment (Spark: 3.3.2)

I have already added the following config:

```py
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy","LEGACY")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: interestingly, "201602" has a week date of `2016-01-03`, which should've been week 01. i think spark is unable to differentiate between 201553 and 201601, and ends up resulting `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is known issue with extracting weeks with pyspark to_date functions [Ref1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-38571)

You can either use `udf` function to parse this format via python.
Example

```
from datetime import datetime
@F.udf('date')
def parse_week(date_week):
    # 1 is considered as the start day of the week to consider 
    # 1= Monday (1-7 for weekday)
    return datetime.strptime(date_week + '1', '%G%V%u')
df.withColumn("date", parse_week('BIC_YCALWK_TO')).show()

+-------------+----------+
|BIC_YCALWK_TO|      date|
+-------------+----------+
|       202252|2022-12-26|
|       201553|2015-12-28|
|       201901|2018-12-31|
|       999952|9999-12-27|
|       201501|2014-12-29|
|       999952|9999-12-27|
+-------------+----------+
```

Why is the format `%G%V%u`
As per the Python documentation, we cannot use `%G%V%` ISO Format only  because

> '%G' must be used with the ISO week directive '%V' and a weekday directive ('%A', '%a', '%w', or '%u'). That's why we need to add +1 for '%u' parse format. This is reference for the [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue12006)

Please check this [Live Notebook](https://notebooks.gesis.org/binder/jupyter/user/apache-spark-w3z7inz1/notebooks/python/docs/source/getting_started/pyspark_week_issue.ipynb)  for running example

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was trying to avoid UDFs as the databricks cluster we are using is a shared Unity Catalog one and it does not support UDFs it seems. Going to have to use it in a standard cluster for now.